# Do not show ANY login form in keycloak but call directly the custom IDP authentication endpoint

Tags: keycloak

We have our own CRM portals and we want to offer OpenID based User authentication and authorization.
To achieve this we have decided to use Keycloak.

The flow we formalized is below and we are stuck due to may be not knowing much of the configurations inside Keycloak or may be its not possible.

- User visits our existing CRM login page where he/she provides the username and password.
- On click of Login the keycloak custom Identity provider should authenticate the user
- Keycloak should receive the authentication success response and generate the JWT token
- User is redirected back to CRM dashboard with the help of redirect_url configured in custom IDP.

What we have done till now,

1. Created a custom IDP inside Keycloak.
2. Configured all endpoints in this custom IDP
3. No custom authentication flow yet, all defaults i.e. First login flow is set to 'first broker login'

Challenges we are facing currently,

1. User on our CRM login page (Not the keycloak login form) and click on login button
2. The Keycloak login form is shown to user. **We dont want any keycloak login pages.** but instead the custom IDP endpoints should be executed and a JWT is returned back to redirected CRM application.

Is this possible to achieve the flow I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt the browser Authentication Flow

Authentication -> Flows -> Browser

There you find the `Identity Provider Redirector`. Click Configure and specify a `Default Identity Provider` (you need the alias of your IDP there)

[image]

Normally all available IdentityProviders are listed beside the login form. But if a DefaultIdentityProvider is configured, KC immediately redirects to the external IDP.